# Difference between : and , in numpy

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

Some resources have mentioned that in `numpy`'s array slicing, `array[2,:,1]` results in the same as `array[2][:][1]` , but I do not get the same ones in this case:

```
array3d = np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4]],[[5, 6], [7, 8]], [[9, 10], [11, 12]]])
array3d[2,:,1]
out: array([10, 12])
```

**and:**

```
array3d[2][:][1]
out: array([11, 12])
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**some resources** is wrong!

```
In [1]: array3d = np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4]],[[5, 6], [7, 8]], [[9, 10], [11, 12
   ...: ]]])
In [2]: array3d
Out[2]: 
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 3,  4]],

       [[ 5,  6],
        [ 7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10],
        [11, 12]]])
```

When the indices are all scalar this kind of decomposition works:

```
In [3]: array3d[2,0,1]
Out[3]: 10
In [4]: array3d[2][0][1]
Out[4]: 10
```

One index reduces the dimension, picking one 'plane':

```
In [5]: array3d[2]
Out[5]: 
array([[ 9, 10],
       [11, 12]])
```

`[:]` on that does nothing - it is not a place holder by itself.  Within the multidimensional index it is a slice - the whole thing in that dimension.  We see the same behavior with lists.  `alist[2]` returns an element, `alist[:]` returns a copy of the whole list.

```
In [6]: array3d[2][:]
Out[6]: 
array([[ 9, 10],
       [11, 12]])
```

Remember, `numpy` is a python package.  Python syntax still applies at all levels.  `x[a][b][c]` does 3 indexing operations in sequence, 'chaining' them.  `x[a,b,c]` is one indexing operation, passing a tuple of to `x`.  It's numpy code that interprets that tuple.

We have to use a multidimensional index on the remaining dimensions:

```
In [7]: array3d[2][:,1]
Out[7]: array([10, 12])
In [8]: array3d[2,:,1]
Out[8]: array([10, 12])
```

The interpreter actually does:

```
In [9]: array3d.__getitem__((2,slice(None),1))
Out[9]: array([10, 12])

In [11]: array3d.__getitem__(2).__getitem__((slice(None),1))
Out[11]: array([10, 12])
```